# how to convert byte array to string in binary reader in c#?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

i have this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("mama.bin", FileMode.Truncate));

        bw.Write("Hello world");




        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("mama.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(8);
        string x = BitConverter.ToString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(x);




        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

in the output i get this -> 0B-48-65-6C-6C-6F-20-77

how can i convert byte[] to my correct string ??
and i think this is a string encoding ?

can any one help me

Thanks :)

Comment: Dont use A BinaryWriter - Reader. Use StreamWriter - Reader instead

Comment: or use `ReadString` (as you used `Write(string)`)

Comment: Yeah i know i can use the ReadString or stream writer but i have question , can i convert bytes to string and get correct value like in double :)

Comment: Try following :             byte[] input = { 0x0B, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x77 };
            string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input);

Comment: @jdweng ohh thanks it is working but in below answer that innat3 wrote he used utf8 and you used ASCII are there any difference or it is the same thing :)

Comment: Encoding using UTF8 doesn't change characters (except 0x80 as far as I know) while ASCII encoding will remove non printable characters (like a Bell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
string x = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```